# html beginner coding with notepad

Tags: html, css, alignment, center, notepad

Hi I study mediadeveloping and I have a question.
I have put a sentence in my html file but it won't show when I open the file in a browser.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="nl">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
    #naam      {
                font-weight: bold;
              }
        #schuin    {
                font-style: italic;
              }
    #centreren {
        text-align: center;
          }

        </style>

    <title>
    opgave 3.1 Stijn Bastiaansen
</title>

</head>

    <body>
    Dit is mijn eerste website.

        <p> Mijn naam is: <span id="naam"> Stijn Bastiaansen. </span> </p>

        <p> <span id="schuin"> Ik volg deze opleding aan het ICT-Lyceum van het Roc Tilburg. </span> </p>

        <p> <span id="centreren> Tekst centreren </span> <p>

        <p align="right"> of rechts uitlijnen </P> 

        <p>kan ik ook al.

    </body>

</html>
```

The browser is not showing tekst centreren

Comment: If you are really coding with notepad, do yourself a big favor and [get the (free) notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org). It adds quote/bracket/parenthesis matching, syntax highlighting, and (most important of all) FTP component that auto-uploads your changed file as soon as you Save.

Comment: Close the id="centreren" .

Comment: Your first step in debugging should be to [validate your document](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Closing since the issue is a missing quote, essentially a typo

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `<span>` element will not fit to full line width so (unless it has a fixed width) it won't display centered text (because its width is exactly text/content width).

Just apply the style to an element that will span to the whole line width (such as `<p>`):

```
<p id="centreren"> Tekst centreren</p>
```

It doesn't affect rendering of such simple example (because browsers are pretty *easy* with HTML) but there are other <strike>errors</strike> things you should pay attention:

- Value of `id` attribute for `centreren` isn't enclosed with quotes, they're optional (and even when unbalanced most modern browsers will *understand* them). In your example you open it but you don't close it and some browsers may fail for that.
- Last paragraph element `<p>` isn't closed. Closing tag for paragraphs is optional (like many others HTML closing tags) but IMO it helps a lot readibility. Especially for newbies, for example, a `<ul>` tag will *close* paragraph because it's forbidden inside `<p>` but at first (and second too) look you may think it's a child node of paragraph itself.

Comment: The closing tag for paragraph elements is optional.

Comment: @cimmanon yes, in this short example is pretty useless (even if it makes it more clear) but in a more complex page (where not allowed tags may be present) IMO is much better to always close them (because it may not validate something else)

Comment: Validation is not going to magically fail because of a missing closing paragraph tag when the specification clearly says they are optional.  Yes, it adds clarity to the markup (and I do recommend closing all tags), but to say that's the cause of the OP's problem is dishonest.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you just forgot to close `<p>` and also the span id is missing a quote

This should work:

```
<body>
    Dit is mijn eerste website.

        <p> Mijn naam is: <span id="naam"> Stijn Bastiaansen. </span> </p>

        <p> <span id="schuin"> Ik volg deze opleding aan het ICT-Lyceum van het Roc Tilburg. </span> </p>

        <p> <span id="centreren"> Tekst centreren </span> </p>

        <p align="right"> of rechts uitlijnen </p> 

        <p>kan ik ook al.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: The closing tag for paragraph elements is optional.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you haven't closed the paragraph tag in the last line

kan ik ook al

this should work
paragraph close tag is not required in HTML unlike XHTML, but it would be a better practice to close all open tags in HTML.

Output:

```
Dit is mijn eerste website.
Mijn naam is: Stijn Bastiaansen.

Ik volg deze opleding aan het ICT-Lyceum van het Roc Tilburg.

of rechts uitlijnen

kan ik ook al.
```

Comment: "I guess you haven't closed the paragraph tag in the last line" — Not explicitly, but they don't have to, and doing so won't make any difference.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in your last sentence of your body text. You have to close the paragraph tag in order for it to be recognized and presented on your site.

Comment: Hi! Please include some code. Also, is your answer different than the other answers already provided?

Comment: This is incorrect. The end tag for the `p` element is optional.

Answer (score -3):

```
<body>
    Dit is mijn eerste website.
    <p> Mijn naam is: <span id='naam'> Stijn Bastiaansen. </span></p>
    <p>
        <span id='schuin'> Ik volg deze opleding aan het ICT-Lyceum van het Roc Tilburg.</span> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <span id='centreren'> Tekst centreren </span> 
    </p>        
    <p align='right'> of rechts uitlijnen </p> 
    <p>kan ik ook al.</p>
</body>
```

here's the result. http://jsfiddle.net/BCxNb/

Comment: The OP isn't asking about centering the content, they're asking why the content isn't displaying at all.